# Image is getting "object Object" as src in bigcommerce

Tags: product, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I want to show my product items images using GQL in my product-view page. I can show my SKUs, UPCs, MPNs using GQL in table. but in image receiving src value as "object Object".
Here's my post link too & here you can see my theme's images:

https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D54O00007QVVk7SAH/image-is-getting-object-object-in-src

Comment: `{{node.defaultImage.url}}`, you even highlighted it in this screenshot: https://support.bigcommerce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=0684O00000JK4vl&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05T4O00001MNh14&page=0

Comment: @GrafiCode Yeah exactly It did! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{node.defaultImage.url}}
Refrence to the comment above is the accurate answer to this post.